# IPv6 access to Net Eng Stack Exchange (Or any other SE site for that matter)

Tags: feature-request

Is there a roadmap from the SE staff to get native IPv6 access to networkengineering.stackexchange.com?  Or as the title says, to any Stack Exchange site?

I've found several questions over on the Stack Overflow Meta site, such [as this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21592/would-it-be-possible-for-stack-overflow-to-be-accessible-over-ipv6), but nothing really definitive from an actual SE moderator/admin.

For our site in particular, *as a networking focused site*, I think it is sort of a "badge of shame" that we have no IPv6 access.

I am well aware of the many hurdles a site this size will face with IPv6 deployment.  So, please don't misunderstand me; I'm not asking "Why isn't it here now!?" or demanding "Give it to me tomorrow!".  I want to know if there is a plan in place, and what kind of timeline it might be.

And if there isn't one, I think they've got plenty of community members (here on Network Engineering or over at Server Fault) who could probably be talked into donating a little consulting time to help them out...  ;)